# How to install epson l130 printer ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, printing

Epson L130 printer driver will not install on Ubuntu 16.04 - Error message Dependency is not satisfiable: lsb (>=3.2) although lsb 4.1 installed

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to download the Epson drivers anymore.

Just run this in a terminal and drivers + utilities will install:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

Comment: After install this, printer started to accept job, but it print 0.001 opacity based very lite print. any suggestion to fix